# Problema libreria optimlib en Dev C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy trabajando con la librería Optimlib en Dev C++, pero las directivas para instalarlo entiendo que solo están para Linux. He añadido el include a los directorios de c++ de Dev C++, pero al compilar me aprece el error al utilizar el comando de la librería, el error es el siguiente:

logit_reg.cpp:(.text.startup+0x97): undefined reference to `optim::de(arma::Col&, std::function const&, arma::Col*, void*)>, void*)'

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? He probado a declarar dentro del código las funciones de la librería y tampoco funciona (tal y como se propone en el post al que se me linkeó). Muchas gracias!!

Comment: He mirado la solución que se propone en el enlace del post, y nada, no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar los archivos de la librería a la raíz de tu proyecto e incluirlas con:

```
#include"nombrelibreria"
#include"cabeceras"
```

etc, usando "" puedes incluir cabeceras que estén en la raíz del proyecto, también trata de dar mas info sobre que SO estas usando etc.

Comment: El problema no es de compilación sino de enlazado... los includes que usa actualmente están bien y no necesita cambiarlos

Comment: #ifndef _optim_lbfgs_HPP
#define _optim_lbfgs_HPP


bool lbfgs(arma::vec& init_out_vals, std::function<double (const arma::vec& vals_inp, arma::vec* grad_out, void* opt_data)> opt_objfn, void* opt_data);
bool lbfgs(arma::vec& init_out_vals, std::function<double (const arma::vec& vals_inp, arma::vec* grad_out, void* opt_data)> opt_objfn, void* opt_data, algo_settings_t& settings);


#endif

En concreto al intentar meter en el código, segun la solución de hilo al que me enlazas, es esta línea la que da error, al no entender el "algo_settings".

Comment: Lo solucioné creando unos "includes" que se podían enlazar directamente mediante comandos de Cygwin (tal y como explicaban en su página). Ya funciona correctamente, mil gracias.